# Remove line and the one before that matches pattern using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file containing the following text:

```
>seq 1
GAA--ACGAA
>seq 2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq 3
GACG-CG-AG
>seq 4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

How can I delete the lines containing "-" and the ones before it using `sed`?
Expected output:

```
>seq 2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq 4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

I have tried `sed -e '/-/-1d' file`, but I get `` sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `-' ``

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 'N;/-/d' input_file
>seq 2
CATCTCGGGA
>seq 4
ATTCCGTGCC
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;/\n.*-/!{P;D};:a;s/.*//;N;/\n.*-/ba;D' file
```

Open a two line window and if the second line does not contains `-` print/delete the first line and repeat.

Otherwise, empty the pattern space and append another line and if the second line does contain `-` repeat this part again.

Otherwise, delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. This deletes the previous line and any multiples of lines containing `-`. Also the `D` deletes upto and including the first newline in the pattern space and the sed cycle omits the automatic reading of the next line into the pattern space if the pattern space is not empty.